# Cannot install OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility

Tags: opshub

Installing the opshub migration tool while logged in as user 'Administrator' fails during setup with error message

```
ops-003: You are not running the installer with appropriate settings! Please verify the user running the installer is an Admin user.
```

I searched for this error message in google and looked in the Q&A Visual Studio Gallery site for the migration tool but found nothing concerning this error.

I am trying to install the utility on a virtual server logged in as Administrator.

Download version is:
OVSMU-V1.1.0.005
Operating system:
Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter with Service Pack 1 (This is the machine where TFS 2012 is installed).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, are you facing this during the installation process? Can you divulge the details about the step where you get this error?

Comment: Of course: I start the executable and after confirming the security warning about running files from the internet, the OPS-003 message appears and the setup stops. Even running the setup explicitly via context menu "Run as Administrator" (which should be the same as I'm logged in as "Administrator", I'm getting the same result. The is no welcome dialog or any other Setup-Wizard appearing, just the 003 error.

Comment: can you send screen shot to ovsmu@opshub.com, support will verify and update proper answer/resolution here.

Comment: We are having the same issue today. Any resolution to this?

Comment: I have solved this issue by installing opshub on seperate machine which folows opshub guideline to not install opshub on the same machine where TFS is running. This way, no installation issues occurred and I was able to successfully trasfer the data to visual studio online.